Why use Modifier instead of modifier
enter image description here
I don't kow why.......
Why can’t we directly pass the function’s parameters to the place marked by the red line?
if we use "modifier", the column will lose the "Center vertically" effect?
fun GreetingText(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = message,
            fontSize = 100.sp,
            lineHeight = 116.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
        Text(
            text = from,
            fontSize = 36.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 16.dp)
                .padding(end = 16.dp)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        )
    }
}


To prevent unintended side effects, it's important to pass the modifier argument (which holds styling information) directly to the top-level composable (Column in this case).
For example if you try to add .padding to that modifier, it will be applied two times and this is not a good practise.
Instead of doing this you can declare generic Modifier to use several times.
For more information check this link.
